# Powershell SQL server update query

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Database and update any record that the changed field is = to 'x'.  I'm able to query the database but when I attempt to do an update I get this error:

```
Fill : Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
```

This is the script I'm using:

```
#Create SQL Connection
$con = new-object "System.data.sqlclient.SQLconnection"

#Set Connection String
$con.ConnectionString =(“Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=IDCards;Integrated Security=SSPI”)
$con.open()

$sqlcmd = new-object "System.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand"
$sqlcmd.connection = $con
$sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 600000
#$sqlcmd.CommandText = “select * from tblPhotoID where changed = 'X'”
$sqlcmd.CommandText = “UPDATE dbo.tblPhotoID SET Changed = '1' WHERE Changed ='X'”
$adapter = New-Object system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter ($sqlcmd.CommandText, $con)
$set = New-Object system.data.dataset
$adapter.Fill($set)
```

There are about 4000 records that would updated currently.  The script runs about 30 secs before timing out.  I've tried increasing the command timeout and gotten the same results.

Comment: What happens if you try to update just one record?

Answer (score 25):

Your update statement is not going to return a recordset so there is nothing to fill the dataset. You instead want to try the following:

```
#Create SQL Connection
$con = new-object "System.data.sqlclient.SQLconnection"

#Set Connection String
$con.ConnectionString =(“Data Source=sb-inft-orange.ads.iu.edu;Initial Catalog=IDCards;Integrated Security=SSPI”)
$con.open()

$sqlcmd = new-object "System.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand"
$sqlcmd.connection = $con
$sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 600000
$sqlcmd.CommandText = “UPDATE dbo.tblPhotoID SET Changed = '1' WHERE Changed ='X'”
$rowsAffected = $sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: That helped in that i'm not getting the timeout.  But the update doesnt actually update any of the data in the database.

Comment: I double checked the code on my machine (PowerShell 3.0) and I found that I needed to add a set of parentheses after the ExecuteNonQuery method call otherwise I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have used `$adapter.Fill($set)` FYI, It is used to add rows in the DataSet to match those in the data source.Instead you can use `$adapter.Update($Set)` I think this will solve your problem. Also you can use `$sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
#Create SQL Connection

$con = new-object "System.data.sqlclient.SQLconnection"
#Set Connection String
$con.ConnectionString =(“Data Source=sb-inft-orange.ads.iu.edu;Initial 
Catalog=IDCards;Integrated Security=SSPI”)
$con.open()

$sqlcmd = new-object "System.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand"
$sqlcmd.connection = $con
$sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 600000
$sqlcmd.CommandText = “UPDATE dbo.tblPhotoID SET Changed = '1' WHERE Changed ='X'”
$sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$cn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection ( "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog.......)
$q = "select ...  from .. "
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($q, $cn)
$da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60
```

Comment: This is based on Select...does not work as OP was expecting for an Update.  An action that inherently has no need for a DataAdapter or DataSet